# How to run php-file on nginx-server?

Tags: php, nginx, server, config

currently I'm trying to run a php file on my nginx server. I downloaded all packages, changed the config file, but it is still not working. I can open my index.html, but when I open my php file it just downloads it.
[image]

[image]

[image]

My code of the config file:
server {
listen 80 default_server;

```
root /var/www/html;
index index.html index.htm index.php index.nginx-debian.html;

server_name test;

location / {

    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix: /var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock
}
```

}

Please help me.

Comment: Could be a problem caused by php-fpm. Do you have `/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock`?

Comment: yes i have, already checked

Answer (score 0):

Try this I pulled from a working server

```
server {
        listen 80;
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        server_name 10.0.0.19;
 
        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
 
        location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
        }
}
```

I only changed the fpm and server name since well the server is using 7 and the server_name was the ip of the server...I put yours

Comment: Hmm I don't what's wrong. Thanks for the help but it didn't work for me

Comment: You probably missed something on the dependencies..maybe some files were not loaded

Answer (score -1):

Your configuration file is invalid, and It may not applied. Try this and run `sudo nginx -t && sudo systemctl restart nginx`.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.php index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name test;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```